# unsetting a variable

Tags: php

I have some code here which looks as following:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['addToCart'])) {
    foreach ($_SESSION["addToCart"] as &$value){
        if ($value['titel'] == $titel){ 
            $value['aantal'] = $aantal;
            if($value['aantal'] == 0){
                unset($value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so when 'aantal' = 0, I want to delete that record, but it doesn't, it just gives back the result and 'aantal' is 0 instead of the record being removed from the session.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.unset.php): "When you unset the reference, you just break the binding between variable name and variable content. This does not mean that variable content will be destroyed."

You'd want to do something like this:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['addToCart'] as $key => &$value) {
   if ($value['aantal'] == 0) {
      unset($_SESSION['addToCart'][$key]);
   }
}
```

Think of it like filesystem's symbolic links. When you destroy a symbolic link, it doesn't destroy the file it was linked to.

Comment: That's the only there is way to unset array keys. You're most likely doing it wrong.

Comment: Probably me explaining bad again, i dont want to completely remove the addToCart session, its an associative array with arrays within it, so when the record "aantal" from one of those arrays equals 0, i want to remove that array, not the entire session

Comment: I found it. Was indeed what you were saying, just had to add the name of the session. unset($_SESSION['addToCart][$key]

Comment: Yeah I just revised my answer as you were typing this.

Answer (score 1):

According to the PHP docs (http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php), a variable that is passed by reference is only destroyed in the local context. Try `$value = null;`

Comment: Setting a variable to `null` doesn't destroy it though.

Comment: This empties al the values but the record is still existing

Comment: By record, do you mean a row in a database? Because if that's the case, you're going about this the completely wrong way.

Comment: no, i mean the row in my S_SESSION, my english isnt that good so i'm having a hard time explaining, sorry for that

Comment: Ok. Setting $value to null should work, since it is a reference variable from $_SESSION and the assignment would find it's way back into $_SESSION. I'm not really sure what else you could possibly want to do to the data, the garbage collector will take care of removing it from memory.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may stem from the fact that $value is a value variable, a copy of the $_SESSION["addToCarT"][current_index].  You should be setting the $_SESSION["addToCart"][current_index] to null or unsetting that, not the copies variable in the limited scope.

Comment: But isnt that what &$value is for? Ithought that this makes 'value' the actual record instead of a copy?

Comment: Think of it like filesystem's symbolic links. When you destroy a symbolic link, it doesn't destroy the file it was linked to.